# Share catalog is taking too much time to reindex

Tags: reindex, performance, sharedcatalog

We have almost 900+ shared catalogs across multiple stores in one setup, the pricing is assigned to each product.

When we are doing reindexing. It is taking 3-4 hours to complete Catalog Product Permissions index and Price Index.

Can anyone please help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying to migrate the rules to customer groups with discounts to products based on tiers.

If it can't be applied in your case and you have a multi-store setup, you can also reduce the scope of your configuration to optimize it, you just need to change the store and website for each custom catalog rule created.

[image: Share Catalog Magento 2 optimization stores]
[image: Share Catalog Magento 2 optimization websites]

Make sure the exclude the websites you don't need in each shared catalog too.

[image: Magento Shared Catalog Optimization]

Then run these commands via Magerun 2.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar db:query "DELETE from cron_schedule WHERE status='error' OR status='pending' OR status='missed'";
./var/n98-magerun2.phar db:console;
```

Inside your DB run these:

```
TRUNCATE catalog_category_flat_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_category_product_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_data_exporter_products_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_product_attribute_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_product_category_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_product_flat_cl;
TRUNCATE catalog_product_price_cl;
TRUNCATE cataloginventory_stock_cl;
TRUNCATE catalogrule_product_cl;
TRUNCATE catalogrule_rule_cl;
TRUNCATE catalogsearch_fulltext_cl;
TRUNCATE customer_dummy_cl;
TRUNCATE design_config_dummy_cl;
TRUNCATE elasticsuite_categories_fulltext_cl;
TRUNCATE elasticsuite_thesaurus_cl;
TRUNCATE inventory_cl;
TRUNCATE salesrule_rule_cl;
TRUNCATE targetrule_product_rule_cl;
TRUNCATE targetrule_rule_product_cl;

UPDATE `mview_state` SET `version_id` = '0';
TRUNCATE queue_lock;
```

And finalize it by running the reindex again.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar index:reset
php -d memory_limit=-1 ./var/n98-magerun2.phar index:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Fast reindex use that command** : nohup php bin/magento indexer:reindex > indexingStatus.txt &

Comment: It won't actually optimize it, it won't finish the processing when you close your terminal.